# only allow admin user to update a particular field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model that I want to allow normal users to edit the main fields in the model (name,telephone etc) on the same model I have a status field.

I have added it to:

```
protected $guarded = ['id','status','formType'];
```

I only want the Admin user to be able to update that field, so i only display the status field on the form when the user is an admin.

then in my controller I check if the user is an admin then then set the status like this:

```
        if (Auth::check())
            $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->is_admin()) {
            $venue->status = $request->input('status');
        }
```

This seems quite messy. is there a better way of protecting from update except for an admin.

thanks

Comment: Simple controller logic or setting up authorization to use in the controller would probably the way to go here.  Did you read up on authorization at laravel.com/docs?

Comment: It seems that you have valid & working code, could you post this to the correct exchange site, which I believe is [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).